# How to check if input is in a array and print the corresponding element of another array?

Tags: python

If I'm making a "translator" and for each letter i'm assigning a world (like cat = a, dog = b...) can i just make 2 arrays where the "translation" of every letter in the first array corresponds to the element with the same position of the letter itself in the other array for example

```
array_1 = ["a", "b"]
array_2 = ["cat", "dog"]

def translation(phrase):
     translation = ""
     for letter in phrase:
     if letter in array_1:
          translation += #the element of array_2 in the same position of the element of array_1 witch is equal to letter

     return translation

print(translation(input()))
```

Comment: Those are not arrays, those are `list` objects. But you probably just want to use a `dict` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use two lists. However, a much better solution is to use dictionary values. That way, you simply enter a key (the input word) and are given the value it translates to. You can use this:

```
dictionary = { 'a': 'cat', 'b' : 'dog'}
```

and can easily add more translations with the form of `input : output` to more easily see what each input translates to. The way to then translate a word is to, for each input, type

```
dictionary[input]
```

and you will be given the correct output. For example, `dictionary['a']` will return `'cat'` in this example. This cuts away on time counting what position each key and output are in each list to make sure they match up.

To translate multiple characters in a row, use this:

```
dictionary = { 'a': 'cat', 'b' : 'dog'}
undecoded="abbabaa"
decoded=""
for i in undecoded:
    decoded=decoded+dictionary[i]
print(decoded)
```

Hope this helps! -Theo

Edit: As juanpa.arrivillaga mentions, if you already have two lists that you want to transition into dictionary form, you can use `dictionary=dict(zip(array_1, array_2))`

Comment: it translates only one element per time, if I write ab it says      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrea/PycharmProjects/charm_traduttore/venv/traduttore gorg-ita.py", line 4, in <module>
    dictionary[a]
KeyError: 'ab'

Comment: @AndreaPinaroli Edited my answer. The reason it would be *much* better for you to use a dictionary is because it's *much* easier to edit an earlier definition. If you have two lists that are each 100 words long, it's very time-consuming to find the 65th element in each list. A dictionary lets you see the untranslated and translated words side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.index()` function to find correct index:

```
array_1 = ["a", "b"]
array_2 = ["cat", "dog"]

phrase = 'acba'

def translation(phrase):
    for letter in phrase:
        yield array_2[array_1.index(letter)] if letter in array_1 else None

for t in translation(phrase):
    if t:
        print(t)
    else:
        print('NOT FOUND')
```

Prints:

```
cat
NOT FOUND
dog
cat
```

Edit: to join the phrases to one string you could to this for example:

```
final_string = ''.join(t if t is not None else '' for t in translation(phrase))
print(final_string)
```

Prints:

```
catdogcat
```

Comment: thank you, how can I print the words all in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a dict like :

```
d = {array_1[n] :array_2[n] for n in range(len(array_1))}
```

Comment: this could just be `dict(zip(array_1, array_2))`